# What's a better way to bind header checkbox to user control's datacontext?

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I have a workable solution but I'm pretty convinced there's a better way of writing this.

I have a User Control with a Data Grid inside.  The Data Grid's `ItemsSource` is set to `{Binding Path=MyView}` where `MyView` is an `ICollectionView` property of the View Model.  The User Control's data context is set to the View Model.

In the data grid, I have a check box header.  I want to bind the `IsChecked` state of the checkbox to a property in the View Model.

This is what I have so far and it seems to work, but I'm concerned this binding is unnecessarily complex.  The UI is pretty basic so I would expect the binding to be more straightforward to write than it was.

Is there a better way to express such a binding?

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
         <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Views:MyUserControlClass}}, Path=DataContext.AllRowsSelected}" />
    </DataTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In such situations I use

```
ElementName=userControl
```

instead of

```
RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Views:MyUserControlClass}}
```

Also you can use

```
{Binding Parent.DataContext.AllRowsSelected, ElementName=LayoutRoot}
```

In this case I assume that **LayoutRoot** is the name of the element who's parent is the user control. `Parent` is its property. So binding is set to parent's DataContext property.

I prefer the last variant, because providing name for user control limits its usage.

EDIT

About **LayoutRoot**. This name is often provided for the top element in a Window or a UserControl, or just some layout:

```
<Window ...>
    <Grid Name="LayoutRoot">
        ...
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

There's nothing special about this name. Just often used. Same situation as with namespace aliases in xaml: sys (points to mscorlib), local (points to your application namespace), etc.

Comment: sorry am new to WPF.  The second answer reads more straightforwardly but where do I define LayoutRoot?  Or is that a special keyword?

Comment: Sorry for not being specific enough. See my edit. Please tell me if I'm not clear

Comment: A quick question about your approach -- it works, but I get some Resharper warnings: Cannot resolve symbol 'DataContext '.  Any way around that?

Comment: Unfortunately I have no experience using Resharper. My guess is following. The Parent property is of DependencyObject type. But DataContext is a property of FrameworkElement class. So I guess it warns that Parent doesn't have DataContext property, and in general it's right. FrameworkElement derives from UIElement, which derives from Visual, which derives from DependencyObject. All elements you are using in XAML are either FrameworkElement or Freezable or ContentElement - these are three possible branches after UIElement. But you won't use bindings for last two ones. So it's ok.

Comment: For workaround you will need to cast types in binding. But that's...I don't know...that scares me much more than warnings ;)